# from XML to XSLT transforming Tags

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I would like to transform this file to xml format using xslt

Our initial xml file.
I want to see the output without any values. But when I use this code, the output contain exist stuff that I really don't care. **My goal is find matching beetween 'Exercise1' and firstExercise.** So, when we find Exercise1 it should be transformated to firstExercise and so on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<option>
    <Exercise1>
        <ExerciseTime>
            <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </ExerciseTime>
    </Exercise1>
    <Exercise2>
        <ExerciseTime>
            <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </ExerciseTime>
    </Exercise2>
    <Exercise3>
        <ExerciseTime>
            <hourMinuteTime>00:00:00</hourMinuteTime>
        </ExerciseTime>
    </Exercise3>
</option>
```

Comment: When "designing" xml documents, usually care is taken to see the difference between structure and content. You can think of it in analogy of defining structs in some programming language. And then a sequence of those structs. Thinking along this line, you would have `Sequence of Exercise` as structure and then Exercise instances containing different data but having same structure. `<Exercise name="first"> ... </Exercise>`. Transformations then usually are about structure, rather than content.

Comment: Thanks. but this stuff should be writing the same like above. I mean I just want to transfer only tag (not a value) of element. <Exercise1> transfer to firstExercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, XSLT 3 can do that with e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(), '^Exercise[0-9]+$')]">
    <xsl:element name="{format-integer(xs:integer(substring-after(local-name(), 'Exercise')), 'w;o', 'en')}Excercise">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

I think, use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` to ensure the other stuff is copied through.

Comment: This works!!! Thanks! But in result we also see the values. But in my case i eally don't needed it

Comment: @lamfitz, well, perhaps `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` is more appropriate then, or perhaps removing the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` which processes the children/contents.

Comment: So that's what the question was about? Wow, you should get a trophy from Penn & Teller for this.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks very much. I've played around this code, but can you share easiest way with using XPath? firstExercise i just want as string output. thanks!

Comment: @lamfitz, don't change or detail your requirements after you got an answer, use the answer and adapt it. If you can't, ask a new question with details of input, exact wanted output, code you tried and how it failed.